# How to get the base url with php

Tags: php, url, path, radix

I need to **extract** the url of the current page where i am. For example:

**URL:** `http://localhost/web/view/tutorialesVideos.php?idvideo=34&tip=1`

**Path:** `http://localhost/web/view/`

Then make an `echo` of the Path.

I understand it is possible with `$_SERVER['']` in php but i can't find the code.

Greetings.

Comment: print_r($_SERVER);die(); and see what you got.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
parse_url
```

Parse a URL and return its components

[parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)